# openvino python inference api import error

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, openvino

I want to use openvino for object detection.
I installed it in conda environment on ubuntu 20.

I added this line in .bashrc:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/envs/openvino/bin/python3/../../lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

I run after:

```
source .bashrc

which python  # gives /home/user/anaconda3/envs/openvino/bin/python
echo $PYTHONPATH # does not return anything
```

I try to import:

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IECore
```

I go this error:

**from .ie_api import *

ImportError: libtbb.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you had carefully followed [these installation step](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_get_started_get_started_linux.html).
You should be able to run the examples if you had set the OpenVINO toolkit and its pre-requisite correctly.

Afterward, you can try to proceed with your attempt.
Please take note that currently only these Operating Systems are supported:

**Ubuntu 18.04.x** long-term support (LTS), 64-bit

CentOS 7.6, 64-bit (for target only)

Yocto Project v3.0, 64-bit (for target only and requires modifications)